# How to return a JSON in @ExceptionHandler when a resource is not found

Tags: json, exception, spring-web

How an application which serves **resources (.js; .css...)** could return **JSON** entities if an error occurs ?

I wrote a `ControllerExceptionHandler` according to [this blog](http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc):

```java
package com.my.rest;

import com.my.rest.errors.ErrorMessage;
import com.my.rest.errors.ErrorMessageFactory;
import com.my.service.errors.NotFoundException;
import com.my.service.errors.ValidationException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;

@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorMessageFactory messageFactory;

    @ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler({NotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleServiceException(RuntimeException e, WebRequest request) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);

        return handleExceptionInternal(e, messageFactory.generateMessage(e), headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }

}
```

If the request URL is: `https://my-server/resources/a.js`, but `a.js` is not found, this *ExceptionHandler* leads to a `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` thrown by `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` because `ContentNegotiationManager` uses a strategy based on the extension `.js`, and determines that `ErrorMessage` is not applicable to the media type `application/javascript`.

**My question is**: Is there a way to ignore the check of media type to always send JSON error responses so that the client-side error management can parse it ?

Thank you